# Playing a video with Flex, ActionScript 3.0 - no UI

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video

I am currently trying to make a game on flex and one of the problems I ran in to is how to play a short animation at the beginning. I found plenty of examples on the web about how to may it from MXML and how to add UI - my goal is to just play it from an AS file with no UI (and, if possible, to embed it into the SWF).

I am quite new to flex so sorry if this question is stupid...

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Read about video class and netstream, there are plenty of example for the same. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html#includeExamplesSummary

Answer (score 3):

- For pure **AS3** (you mentioned as3 file) you can use `Video` object -> check out examples [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html#includeExamplesSummary)
- For **Flex** you can utilize `VideoDisplay` control -> check out examples [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d7f.html)

Both options are used only for display video and don't have playback controls.